# Unix Bash...To sum up each row in a csv file, from the second entry onwards and then find the highest number from the sum of rows

Tags: bash

I have create a one liner that will sum up each row in a csv file, from the second entry onwards. **But I want to find the highest number from the sum of rows**

Example file output: There are thousands of rows

```
03/Mar/2016:00:14,19772,7494,11293,9467
03/Mar/2016:00:15,18041,13241,9715,8968
03/Mar/2016:00:16,17441,13534,9926,9301
03/Mar/2016:00:17,17709,14243,9022,9209
03/Mar/2016:00:18,16368,13535,8761,8313
03/Mar/2016:00:19,17074,13224,8868,7789
03/Mar/2016:00:20,16783,13666,9499,8763
03/Mar/2016:00:21,16665,12962,8821,8862
```

Example script:
This is what I have achieved by calculating each row **but need to just find the highest number from the calculated rows**. Any ideas?

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {sum=0; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {sum+=$i}; print $0,"sum:"sum,}' /tmp/101.20160304.csv
```

cheers

Comment: Thank you it worked a treat

Comment: Thank you it worked a treat.... awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {sum=0; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {sum+=$i}; print $0,"sum:"sum,}' /tmp/101.20160304.csv **| sort  -t  ":" -nrk2 | head -1**

Answer (score 2):

awk is quite capable of remembering a maximum value.

```
awk -F, '
    # for every row, calculate the sum
    {sum = 0; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum += $i}

    # set the max value (if the first row, initialize the max value)
    NR == 1 || sum > max {max = sum}

    END {print max}
' file
```

For your sample data, this is the max:

```
50202
```

Comment: How so? I'm not initializing to zero, I'm initializing to the first row of real data.

Answer (score 1):

you can pipe your awk output to :

```
awk_output|sort  -t':' -nrk4|head -1
```

this does sort by the sum descending, then pick the first row. Of course you can re-write your awk, to do this in one shot.